# How to deploy jekyll on slicehost

Tags: github, jekyll

I have jekyll blog up and running locally. I am not sure how to push the content to slicehost. They have [an instruction page](http://wiki.github.com/mojombo/jekyll/deployment) but I am not able to follow the instruction.

I have all my content on github. Just need to know how to make post-update hook work?

Answer (score 8):

To deploy a generated Jekyll site, you just need to copy the contents of the local `_site` directory to the appropriate remote directory on your server (often `public_html`, but it depends on the server configuration).

Personally, I think the easiest way is to just use `rsync`, assuming you can use `rsync` with your server. Then it's as simple as executing the command

```
$ rsync -avz --delete _site/ user@host:/path/to/web/root
```

to deploy your site. For my Jekyll-based sites, I encapsulate this in a Rake task so I can just do

```
$ rake site:deploy
```

to copy the site to the server.

If you can't use `rsync`, you can always transfer the `_site` directory via FTP, which is also pretty easy to do (and with a bit of Ruby scripting, can be automated using Rake as well).

You *can* use Git, as noted in the Jekyll docs. You will have to have Git installed on your server, and access to using it. If that's the case, you have to create a bare Git repo on your server. In the bare repo, you then create a post-update hook to check out the latest copy of the site. You do this by creating a script at `$BARE_REPO/hooks/post-update` with contents like the following (as noted [here](http://www.taknado.com/en/2009/03/26/deploying-a-jekyll-generated-site/)):

```
#!/bin/sh
unset GIT_DIR && cd /path/to/web/root && git pull
```

You then clone the bare repository to your web root, like so:

```
$ cd /path/to/web/root
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf root
$ git clone /path/to/bare/repo.git root
```

As you can see, it's often easier to use `rsync` or FTP instead of Git.